# How can i speed up this python code?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I recently coded this as a little challenge to see how quick I could do it. Now since its working an such I want to speed it up. It finds all the proper devisors of a number, the highest proper devisor and times how long it all takes. The problem is with number like 5000 it takes 0.05 secs but with numbers like 99999999999 it takes 1567.98 secs.

this the old code I have made a new and improved version below

import time

```
def clearfile(name):
    file = open(name + ".txt", "r")
    filedata = file.read()
    file.close()
    text_file = open(name + ".txt", "w")
    text_file.write("")
    text_file.close()

def start():
    num = input("Enter your Number: ")
    check(num)

def check(num):
    try:
        intnum = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        error(error = "NON VALID NUMBER")
    if(intnum < 0):
        error(error = "POSITIVE NUMBERS ONLY")
    else:
        finddivisor(intnum)

def finddivisor(intnum):
    starttimer = time.time()
    i = 1
    print("\nThe divisors of your number are:"),
    while i <= intnum:
        if (intnum % i) == 0:
            print(i)
            file = open("numbers.txt", "r")
            filedata = file.read()
            file.close()
            text_file = open("numbers.txt", "w")
            text_file.write(str(i) +"\n"+ filedata)
            text_file.close()
        i += 1
    properdivisor(starttimer)

def properdivisor(starttimer):
    file = open("numbers.txt", "r")
    highest = file.readlines()
    print("\nThe Highest Proper Divisor Is\n--------\n" + highest[1] + "--------" + "\nIt took"  ,round(time.time() - starttimer, 2)  ,"seconds to finish finding the divisors.\n")
    restart(errorrestart = "false")

def restart(errorrestart):
    if errorrestart == "false":
        input("Do You Want Restart?\nPress Enter To Restart Or Close The Programe To Leave")
        start()
    elif errorrestart == "true":
        input("\nThere Was An Error Detected.\nPress Enter To Restart Or Close The Programe To Leave")
        start()

def error(error):
    print("\n----------------------------------\nERROR - " + error + "\n----------------------------------")
    restart(errorrestart = "true")

clearfile(name = "numbers")
start()
```

Can someone speed it up for me

EDIT 1

so after looking over it I have now edited it to be moving it away from a file to an array

```
    import time
    from array import *
    def programme():
        num = input("Enter your Number: ")
        try:
            intnum = int(num)
        except ValueError:
           error("NOT VALID NUMBER")
        if(intnum < 0):
            error("POSITIVE NUMBERS ONLY")
        else:
                numbers = array("i",[])
                starttimer = time.time()
                i = 1
                print("\nThe divisors of your number are:"),
                while i <= intnum:
                    if (intnum % i) == 0:
                        numbers.insert(0,i)
                        print(i)
                    i += 1
                print("\nThe Highest Proper Divisor Is\n--------\n" + str(numbers[1]) + "\n--------" + "\n\nIt took"  ,round(time.time() - starttimer, 2)  ,"seconds to finish finding the divisors.\n")    
    def error(error):
        print("\n----------------------------------\nERROR - " + error + "\n----------------------------------\n")
    running = True
    while(running == True):
        programme()
        print("----------------------------------")
        restart = input("Do You Want Restart?")
        restart = restart.lower()
        if restart in ("yes", "y", "ok", "sure", ""):
            print("Restarting\n----------------------------------")
        else:
            print("closing Down")
            running = False
```

New Edit

```
import time, math
from array import *
def programme():
    num = input("Enter your Number: ")
    try:
        intnum = int(num)
        if(intnum < 0):
            error("POSITIVE NUMBERS ONLY")
        else:
            numbers = array("i",[])
            starttimer = time.time()
            i = 1
            print("\nThe divisors of your number are:"),
            while i <= math.sqrt(intnum):
                if (intnum % i) == 0:
                    numbers.insert(0,i)
                    numbers.insert(0,int(intnum/i))
                    print(i,":", int(intnum/i))
                i += 1
            numbers = sorted(numbers, reverse = True)
            print("The Highest Proper Divisor Is\n--------\n",str(numbers[1]) , "\n--------\nIt took"  ,round(time.time() - starttimer, 2)  ,"seconds to finish finding the divisors." )
    except ValueError:
       error("NOT VALID NUMBER")
    except OverflowError:
       error("NUMBER IS TO LARGE")
    except:
       error("UNKNOWN ERROR")

def error(error):
    print("\n----------------------------------\nERROR - " + error + "\n----------------------------------\n")
running = True
while(running):
    programme()
    print("----------------------------------")
    restart = input("Do You Want Restart?")
    restart = restart.lower()
    if restart in ("yes", "y", "ok", "sure", ""):
        print("Restarting\n----------------------------------")
    else:
        print("closing Down")
        running = False
```

Comment: don't `open` and `close` the file so many times

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: do you have to store intermediate values in files?  if you can just leave it in memory it will help a lot

Comment: Also, `clearfile` only needs to be `def clearfile(name): with open(name, 'w') as f: pass`; you open the file twice, but never use the `filedata`.

Comment: user1603472 no I don't have to store them. I decided to do it that way so I could see my results after wards and read them better but there really isn't any need to store them in a file storing them on the memory is just fine

Comment: I edited the finddevisor bit to    `def finddivisor(intnum):
    starttimer = time.time()
    i = 1
    print("\nThe divisors of your number are:"),
    while i <= intnum:
        if (intnum % i) == 0:
            print(i)
            file = open("numbers.txt", "r")
            filedata = file.read()
            file.close()
            text_file = open("numbers.txt", "w")
            text_file.write(str(i) +"\n"+ filedata)
        i += 1
    properdivisor(starttimer)
    text_file.close()` moved closing the text file to the end of the defined module

Answer (score 2):

If you have divisor `a` of number `n` then you can tell one more divisor of `n` `b = n / a`. Moreover if `a <=  sqrt(n)` then `b >= sqrt(n)` and vice versa. It means in your `finddivisor` function you can iterate while `i * i <= n` and print both divisors `i` and `n / i`. 
By the way, you shouldn't open, read and close files in cycle. Open it once before cycle and close after if you need to read/write several times.

Comment: thanks for pointing out I don't need to close the file every time the loop is running so I will move closing the file to my restart bit. It also had a small effect on the time it took to work out the numbers.

Comment: Yes file manipulations don't have significant impact on time at this situation. But if you take into account idea with divisors (i, n/i) you'll get asymptotic speed up.

Comment: well just tried with 5000 and got same time but it took 38 secs off 99999999999 which is a great start

Comment: @OliverPerring: You didn't use Effect's main suggestion, about finding two divisors in each iteration, and stopping once you've passed the square root of the input.

Comment: I edited the code yet again and now its at the bottom of the question but @JohnY you are right I should do it till the square root sorry for over looking that

Comment: @Effect take a look at my new code after I added this idea

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read and rewrite the entire file every time you want to put a single entry into it.  You can just do it once when you know what change you want.  Also you could just append to it.  Maybe something like this:

```
def finddivisor(intnum):
    starttimer = time.time()
    print("\nThe divisors of your number are:")
    divs = set()
    for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(intnum)) +1):
        if intnum % i == 0:
            print(i)
            divs.add(i)
            divs.add(intnum // i)
    with open("numbers.txt", "a") as file:
        file.writelines("{}\n".format(ln) for ln in sorted(divs, reverse=True))
```

also your program flow is building a very deep stack.  Try and flatten it with something like

```
def start():
    clearfile()
    while True:
        n = get_number()
        starttimer = time.time()
        finddivisor(n)
        properdivisor(starttimer)
        input("Press Enter To Restart Or Close The Programe To Leave")
```

in `properdivisor` you dont need to read the whole file either, you just need the first line. so maybe something like:

```
def properdivisor(starttimer):
    with open(FILENAME, "r") as file:
        highest = file.readline().strip()
    print "\nThe Highest Proper Divisor Is"
    print "--------%s--------" % highest
    print "It took %0.2f seconds to finish finding the divisors.\n" % (time.time() - starttimer)
```

AFTER EDIT

Something like this is how I would do it, and it runs less then a second on my box:

```
import math

def get_divisors(n):
    yield 1
    sqroot = int(math.sqrt(n))
    for x in xrange(2, sqroot):
        if n % x == 0:
            yield x
            yield n / x
    if sqroot**2 == n:
        yield sqroot

divisors = sorted(get_divisors(999999999999))
print divisors
```

Comment: wouldn't this add square roots twice?

Comment: i understand this code up until the with open("numbers.txt", "a") bit how does that work I don't quite get it. Sorry if im being dim im sure its obvious.

Comment: `open` with a `'a'` opens the file in append mode.  `with` is a file context manager that makes sure it closes.

Comment: @Cole that is why `divs` is a `set`. since adding this way they are unordered anyway it doesn't hurt.

Comment: oh well that handy to know are there any limitations to this or should I always use this instead of "w" and "r"

Comment: "also your program flow is building a very deep stack" what do you mean by that? Should I get rid of so many defines?

Comment: What I mean by that is don't have every function calling another function.  Let them return and use that return value.

Comment: @OliverPerring file mode `'a'` is only for appending, `'w'` is for writing from the beginning of the file, `'r'` is readonly.  There are other file modes as well. You can read up on them at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: no it reads the second line dude so you do have to read it. my old code writes to file line by line and proper divisor is the largest multiple that isnt its self so that is always on the second line if u get what I mean

Comment: @OliverPerring yes, I read your code. The point is that you don't need to read the entire file.  You also don't need write the original number to the file either.

Comment: @cmd look at my code in the original question. I have made some edits and am now using an array with so many functions (infact only 2) but it still isn't to much faster

Comment: @cmd ive now made another edit going by what you have done take a look in the question

Comment: @OliverPerring is seems to run fairly fast (0.03 seconds).  What was your question about the new code?